# extension for /etc/hosts

Tags: 16.04, hosts

Is it possible to extend the file /etc/hosts on ubuntu16.04?

I have many ubuntu-servers, all servers should use the same /etc/hosts file, except some special entries.
My preffered solution would be an directory (/etc/hosts.d) with some extra files. Then I would be able to copy the original hosts file to every server and store a specialized file in the directory.

Any solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: Has someone experience with the dotdee package? [dotdee manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dotdee.8.html). This seems to be a solution for me.

Comment: Interesting idea, wasn't aware of that tool. But from the question you don't seem to need to generate the file dynamically. You might be better off considering using a full-fledged configuration management solution like Ansible and generate the files from templates.

Comment: Good question. It would be very nice if `/etc/hosts.d/` would work

Comment: @guettli I suggest have a look at things like [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq)

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not possible using standard mechanisms.

[derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) in his [answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60554/133107) suggested the following workarounds:

> 'There are a couple approaches you could use instead:
>
> - Set up a (possibly local-only) DNS server. Some of these give a *lot* of flexibility, and you can definitely spread your host files over multiple files, or even machines. If you're trying to include the same list of hosts on a bunch of machines, then DNS is probably the right answer.
> - Set up some other name service (NIS, LDAP, etc.). Check the glibc NSS docs for what is supported. Personally, I think you should use DNS in most all cases.
> - Make yourself an `/etc/hosts.d` directory or similar, and write some scripts to concatenate them all together (most trivial: `cat /etc/hosts.d/*.conf > /etc/hosts`, though you'll probably want a little better to e.g., sort), and run that script at boot, or from cron, or manually whenever you update the files.